# CyanogenMod Nexus 6 LED Control

Tags: cyanogenmod, 6.0-marshmallow

Yesterday, I upgraded my Nexus 6 from stock Android Marshmallow to CyanogenMod. I have managed to get everything working properly except for controlling the built in LED that is not used by the device's stock Android build. I do not want to use the LED at all, and I've tried disabling it in the settings, but flipping the switch to off did not work, so I instead changed the LED color to black and flipped the switch off. That seemed to solve the problem, until I powered my phone off and tried charging it, at which point the LED came on. When I restarted the phone, it was on again, and the only way I could shut it off was to reboot the phone without it plugged in.

What can I do to solve the problem?